# Parcel/SWC Ignore Next Line

Tags: parceljs, swc-compiler

I'm using Parcel to build some HTML5 banners. When I build the page, the `var clickTag = '...'` gets minified to `var e = '...'`. I scoured the internet for how to ignore a line of javascript in the HTML. Something like this:

```
<script>
   // ignore-next-line
   var clickTag = 'https://www.google.com';
</script>
```